# Process item in a window with Kafka streams

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I'm trying to process some events in a sliding window with kafka stream but I think i don't understand some details of kafka streams so I'm not able to do what I want.

What I have :

- input topic of events with key/value like (Int, Person)

What I want :

- read these events within a sliding window of 10 minutes
- process each element in the sliding window
- filter and count some element, fire some event to an other kafka
  topic  (like if a wrong value is detected)

To be simple: get all the events in a sliding window of 10 minutes, do a foreach on them, compute some stats/events in the context of the window, go to the next window...

What I tried :
I tried to mix the Stream and the processor API like :

```
    val streamBuilder = new StreamsBuilder()
    streamBuilder.stream[Int, Person](topic)
      .groupBy((_, value) => PersonWrapper(value.id, value.name))
      .windowedBy(TimeWindows.of(10 * 60 * 1000L).advanceBy(1 * 60 * 1000L))
// now I have a window of (PersonWrapper, Person) right ?
    streamBuilder.build().addProcessor(....)
```

And now I'd add a processor to this topology to process each events of the sliding window.
I don't understand what is TimeWindowStream and why we should have a KGroupedStream to apply a Window on events. If someone can enlight me about Kafka stream and what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you read the documentation: https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide/dsl-api.html#windowing

1. Windowing is a special form of grouping (grouping based on time)
2. Grouping is always require to compute an aggregation in Kafka Streams
3. After you have a grouped and windowed stream you call `aggregate()` for the actually processing (not need to attach a `Processor` manually; the call to `aggregate()` will implicitly add a `Processor` for you).

> Btw: Kafka Streams does not really support "sliding windows" for aggregation. The window you define is called a *hopping window*.

`KGroupedStream` and `TimeWindowedKStreams` are basically just helper classes and an intermediate representation that allows for a fluent API design.

The tutorial is also a good way to get started: https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/quickstart.html

You should also check out the examples: https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-streams-examples

Comment: Hello Matthias, thank you, I found the answer. What I needed was an aggregation that count the number of element.